# Does Mono / .NET 4.0 implement AppDomain.FirstChanceException?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I am porting a C# app from .NET on Windows to Mono on Linux (both using .NET 4.0). When compiling the code I get the following code:

Error CS1061: Type `System.AppDomain` does not contain a definition for `FirstChanceException` and no extension method `FirstChanceException` of type `System.AppDomain` could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS1061) (V8.Net-Console)

for the following code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException;
```

When looking at `AppDomain` via Assembly Browser I do not see any definition for `FirstChanceException`. Is it missing from Mono or is it some issue on my machine? If it is missing, what alternative is available?

Comment: I just downloaded the Mono 3.2.1 source code and checked. I didn't see a `FirstChanceException` event declared in the AppDomain.cs code. I don't know if there's an alternative or not (I haven't had the need to use this event before), sorry.

Comment: Yes, I've also found this code, so it seems like they just haven't implemented it: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/2c945ffb26b4d54b8fbba6ec1ea8a09084293ce6/mcs/class/corlib/System/AppDomain.cs

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too surprised. Definitely seems like something that would have to be implemented as part of the _runtime itself_ (though I'm no expert on that; I could be completely wrong). I'd suggest maybe contacting the mono team or their specific community to see if there are any future plans to implement it, and if so, what the timeline is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [source file containing AppDomain class](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/2c945ffb26b4d54b8fbba6ec1ea8a09084293ce6/mcs/class/corlib/System/AppDomain.cs), this is not implemented on Mono yet.